# Gatsby watchMode and overlayDrafts not working on S3 static website

Tags: amazon-s3, gatsby, sanity

I have a project with Gatsby that its 'build' is deployed to AWS S3 bucket with static website hosting.

My Gatsby project is using [gatsby-source-sanity](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-sanity/) plugin, that is getting data from [Sanity.i](https://www.sanity.io/)o dataset.

On my non production stages I would like to have a preview and watchMode on so I would not build and deploy the app on every change.

Within this configuration in **gatsby-config.js**:

```
{
      resolve: "gatsby-source-sanity",
      options: {
        projectId: process.env.GATSBY_SANITY_PROJECT_ID,
        dataset:
          process.env.GATSBY_STAGE === "production" ||
          process.env.GATSBY_STAGE === "master" ||
          process.env.GATSBY_STAGE === "preview"
            ? "production"
            : "dev",
        token: process.env.SANITY_TOKEN,
        overlayDrafts:
          process.env.GATSBY_STAGE !== "production" &&
          process.env.GATSBY_STAGE !== "master",
        watchMode:
          process.env.GATSBY_STAGE !== "production" &&
          process.env.GATSBY_STAGE !== "master",
      },
    },
```

When I run the project on localhost and make changes in Sanity Documents, I get the changes instantly, but I am not getting the changes on my deployed version.

How do I achieve to have watchMode on S3 bucket?

Comment: When you mean "changes locally" are you meaning in a `gatsby develop` or in a `gatsby build` command?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `watchMode` in a production environment since the site is already built.

In a `gatsby develop` environment Gatsby exposes a web socket that can listen to data changes from the sources to retrigger the site in develop mode. However, in a `gatsby build,` you can't because the static pages are already built. To trigger a new refresh of the data sources you'll need to trigger a new deployment.

This can be done using webhooks, which will listen to data changes to trigger a new deployment in your bucket.

Related articles:

- https://medium.com/technogise/auto-build-gatsby-application-using-custom-webhook-on-wordpress-c3c5f70ca005
- https://support.gatsbyjs.com/hc/en-us/articles/360052324394-Build-and-Preview-Webhooks